# Разделить строку на 2 равные по количеству символов Swift

Tags: строки, swift

Есть строка String. Как разделить ее на 2 одинаковые по длине строки типа String в Swift 3?

Comment: а если нечетное количество символов, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let string:String = "I will use google before asking stupid questions on SO"

let half: Int = string.characters.count/2
let firstHalf = string[string.startIndex..<string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: half)]
let secondHalf = string[string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: half)..<string.endIndex]


print(firstHalf)
print(secondHalf)
```